# return values of native types of unstubbed invocations

Tags: java, mockito

I have some @Mock object and I didn't specify the return value of calling a method on that object. The method returns int (not Integer). I was surprised to see that Mockito didn't throw a NPE and returned 0. Is this expected behavior?

For example:

```
class Foo {
    public int getInt() {
        return 1;
    }
}
@Mock
private Foo foo;

@InjectMock
private ClassToTest classToTest;

@Test
public void doTest() {
    int a = classToTest.callFoo(); // which calls foo.getInt()
    Assert.AssertEquals(a, 0); // true

}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2):

> By default, for all methods that return value, mock returns null, an empty collection or appropriate primitive/primitive wrapper value (e.g: 0, false, ... for int/Integer, boolean/Boolean, ...).

So yes, this is the expected behavior. You can also override the default stubbing with something like this:

```
@Test
public void doTest() {
    Mockito.when(foo.getInt()).thenReturn(15);
    int a = classToTest.callFoo(); // which calls foo.getInt()
    //Assert.assertEquals(a, 0); // NO LONGER TRUE
    Assert.assertEquals(a, 15);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For methods that return primitive data types, Mockito returns the default value (which is `false` or `0` depending on the type). Java AutoBoxing takes care of any conversions between those primitives and their objectified equivalents (e.g. boolean to Boolean).